# How to remove the captcha through the browser when logging in via phone in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

How to remove the captcha through the browser when logging in via phone in Firebase?

[image]

I didn't find how to remove the Console in Firebase, I can't remove the captcha after clicking the verify button and it goes to the browser with the captcha.